# Big Query Extract With Filter

Tags: google-bigquery

Hello I'm very new in big query. I have some situation where my project needs to import from big query result. Here I'm facing some problems:

1. If I use bq extract, then I cannot use filter or where condition
2. If I use bq query and then save the result into some files, our server cannot process such large data. And some fields in data itself may contain comma and vertical bar character.

Can I achieve the condition where I could export or extract  with filter with the the most efficient ways?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXPORT DATA` statement allows you to combine a query with extracting data to Cloud Storage in a single job.

See more details here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements

```sql
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://mybucket/my-path-prefix/*',
  format='CSV',
  header=true) AS
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM mydataset.mytable WHERE some_condition
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can I run it inside windows cmd? Where should I run this?

Comment: You can run it with the BQ cli, if you have it installed: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#queries

Comment: thank you sir @shollyman for you explanation. have a good day